# Mongoose aggregation & key-value object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to use a value of a field in a collection as a key to my local object (key-value) to get values to a field while aggregating?

Comment: would be helpful if you can give a concrete example of your sample dataset and expected output

Comment: For example,
I got a static object with key (numbers) and values (strings),
I want to make it so that I can get the string by holding keys in a field called "key" and get the value (give the object to mongo to get the value from with the key)

Comment: No, I mean **concrete** dataset . Please help to provide your json documents, the expected output form and your current code attempt